# Sql Server CE - Temporary disable auto increment on a specific column

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, auto-increment

I have this little question that's been on my mind for a while now.

Here it goes:

Is it possible to temporary disable the Auto_Increment on the column ID.

So that I can add a new row to the table and being able specify the ID value when inserting the row.

And then in the end enable the Auto_Increment again, and let do its work as usual?

And if its possible how can I do it?

The table structure is very simple

Column name (attributes)

```
ID (Primary Key, Auto Increment, int, not null)
Name (nvarchar(100), not null)
```

Note:

- The table name is: `People`.
- Let's also consider that the table already has data and cannot be changed.
- The database server is SQL Server CE.
- The SQL commands will be executed in a C# program, if it's of any help.

I really hope its possible, it would come very handy.

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
SqlActions SqlActions = new SqlActions();

SqlCeCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCeCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT People ON", SqlActions.Connection());

try
{
    SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlCeException Error)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Error.ToString());
}

string query = "INSERT INTO People SET (ID, Nome) VALUES (@ID, @Nome)";

SqlCeCommand SqlInsert = new SqlCeCommand(query, SqlActions.Connection());

SqlInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 15);
SqlInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", "Maria");

try
{
    SqlInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlCeException Error)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Error.ToString());
}
```

The connection string is working, I have tried it.

He reports:

> There was an error parsing the query.
>   [ Token line number = 1,Token line
>   offset
>   = 20,Token in error = SET ]

**SOLUTION** *thanks to [OrbMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39430/orbman)*

```
        SqlActions SqlActions = new SqlActions();

        SqlCeCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCeCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT People ON", SqlActions.Connection());
        try
        {
            SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            string query = "INSERT INTO People (ID, Nome) VALUES (@ID, @Nome)";
            SqlCmd.CommandText = query;
            SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 15);
            SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", "Vania");
            SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlCeException Error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Error.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682654/sql-server-ce-3-5-identity-insert)...

Comment: I already had tried that, with no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you can use [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(SQL.80).aspx). I am not sure if this works in all versions.

**Update 2:**

Try this version:

```
SqlActions SqlActions = new SqlActions();
SqlCeCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCeCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT People ON", SqlActions.Connection());
try
{
    SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    string query = "INSERT INTO People (ID, Nome) VALUES (@ID, @Nome)";
    SqlCmd.CommandText = query;
    SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 15);
    SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", "Maria");
    SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlCeException Error)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Error.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I've tried "SET IDENTITY_INSERT People ON" and then i tried to insert some rows specifying the ID, and the program crashes. And VB is only able to say this: "The column cannot be modified. [Column name = id]"

Comment: The same happens if i try add a row and specifying the ID and not running "SET IDENTITY_INSERT". For what i can see i think "SET IDENTITY_INSERT" doesn't as any affect.

Comment: Are you executing it as one semi-colon separated batch statement?

Comment: Separated statement.. According to Sql Server Docs, set indentity_insert works with SQL Server CE 3.5 e newer. Mine is 3.5, do i don't see whats the problem.

Comment: Its in my new edit. PS: Its C# code, i made a mistake before and typed VB in my comment, sorry.

Comment: @Fabio: you are doing it as two queries, you need to do it in one, e.g., `string query = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT People ON;INSERT INTO People SET (ID, Nome) VALUES (@ID, @Nome)";`

Comment: Still not working. "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset
= 31,Token in error = INSERT ]"

Comment: Hmm, ok, try re-using the same command object in your code. I'll post an updated example.

Comment: No luck :( "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset
= 20,Token in error = SET ]" I really don't have idea wants wrong :S Many examples on the web do the same as you told me.

Comment: @Fabio: No that's good! It is complaining about your `INSERT` query syntax now. Remove the word `SET`, it should not be there for an `INSERT`, that is for `UPDATE` queries. I updated my code.

Comment: Bingo. This will save me a lot of trouble in future cases when restoring the database from a xml file. My greatest thanks.