# SQL Server CE query fails to execute in c#, but works in DBMS

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to run a bunch of SQL statements in sql query. The query and the code look as follows:

```
    private void cancelTestCaseCreationWizard()
    {
        string deleteTestCaseCmd = @"
                                    DELETE FROM column_correlation WHERE test_id IN (SELECT test_id FROM test WHERE test_case_id = @tcid); 
                                    DELETE FROM data_range WHERE test_id IN (SELECT test_id FROM test WHERE test_case_id = @tcid); 
                                    DELETE FROM permitted_values WHERE test_id IN (SELECT test_id FROM test WHERE test_case_id = @tcid); 
                                    DELETE FROM test WHERE test_case_id = @tcid; 
                                    DELETE FROM parameter WHERE parameter_set_id IN (SELECT parameter_set_id from parameter_set WHERE test_case_id = @tcid); 
                                    DELETE FROM parameter_set WHERE test_case_id = @tcid; 
                                    DELETE FROM test_case WHERE test_case_id = @tcid;";
        List<SqlCeParameter> param = new List<SqlCeParameter>();
        SqlCeParameter tcid = new SqlCeParameter("@tcid", SqlDbType.Int);
        tcid.Value = reservedTestCaseId;
        param.Add(tcid);
        DatabaseInteraction.DMLQuery(deleteTestCaseCmd, param);
        Dispose();
    }


    public static int DMLQuery(string query, List<SqlCeParameter> parameters)
    {
        int rowsAffected = -1;
        try
        {
            DBConn.Open();
            var tran = DBConn.BeginTransaction();
            SqlCeCommand comm = new SqlCeCommand(query, DBConn, tran);
            foreach (SqlCeParameter par in parameters)
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add(par);
            }
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tran.Commit();
        }
        catch (SqlCeException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error executing DML query \n" + e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return -2;
        }
        DBConn.Close();
        return rowsAffected;
    }
```

After the execution of the above code I get the message:

```
Error executing DML query 
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 41,Token in error = DELETE ]
```

I looked up the value of @tcid and it is correct. The query itself works okay in DBMS. What might cause this error?

Comment: Strange, the third line is a duplicate of the first one.

Comment: Corrected. Still, that did not solve the problem, the exception remains the same.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/682775/468973) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SQL Server Compact does not support batch query execution. You have to
>   run the each statement seperately. You can reuse the SqlCeCommand
>   object to execute more than one query though.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/d6f1db96-8724-4376-990e-3f6da18c2d08/